# ООП в Python. Организация класса с родительским окном и класса с дочерним

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

Собственно есть такой код накиданый мной. Изначально передо мной была задача: Создать приложение с использованием tkinter и ООП подхода к построению GUI, чтоб было главное окно и дочернее, которое вызывается по клику на кнопку. Я новичёк, но погуглив и почитав литературу моё решение вылилось в такой вот код. Есть основной класс Main который наследуется от Frame и является родительским окном, также есть класс Child который наследуется от Toplevel в свою очередь является дочернем окном.

Вопрос состоит в том, на сколько корректно я реализовал данную задачу с профессиональной точки зрения. Хочу мнения опытных Питонистов, данная задача всплывает у многих в той или иной реализации. Есть желания создать базовый шаблон чтоб дальше продолжить реализацию собственного приложения.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        btnOpenDialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Добавить позицию', command=self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, compound=tk.TOP)
        btnOpenDialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def open_dialog(self):
       Child()


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.title('Добавить доходы/расходы')
        self.geometry('400x220+400+300')
        self.resizable(False, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("Домашние финансы")
    root.geometry("650x450+300+200")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пока приложение является демкой, в которой есть только два окошка,  но нет бизнес-логики и сколько-нибудь обобщенной реакции на действия пользователя, сложно сказать, правильно это или нет. Вроде, нормально. Когда вы хотите сделать кастомизированный виджет (в Tcl/Tk это называется "мегавиджет"), то да, логично наследовать его от Frame.

Comment: Изначальный вариант был такой, но мне указали на множественные ошибки [ссылка на исходник](https://gist.github.com/ithobbies/23b014b2974085dff64c2637f1b25995)

Comment: Правильная ссылка, видимо, такая: https://gist.github.com/ithobbies/23b014b2974085dff64c2637f1b25995/ Общий подход: стоит разделять на разные классы все, что касается интерфейса, бизнес-логики и реакции на действия пользователя. Это называется MVC.

Comment: Собственно, мне бы хотелось чтоб Вы сказали на сколько корректно и правильно, с точки зрения специалиста-профессионала, написан код, выдержаны ли все заповеди ООП и здравого смысла...